How to use Deployer to deploy private git?
I am trying to use Deployer (deployer.org) to deploy my laravel project from private git hosted using Gogs (gogs.io). However, when I run dep deploy, I get the error  fatal: could not read Username for 'http://208.113.198.112:8000': terminal prompts disabled
This is what I have with my deploy.php:
set('repository', 'http://208.113.198.112:8000/project/test-deploy.git');

How can I config the Deployer so that it can work with my private git?

You either need to use SSH auth and a git@ instead of HTTPS repo or a link https://username:password@208.113.198.112:8000/project/test-deploy.git. With the second method I would use environment variables and getenv() for the username and password
